# Continuous Integration for Common Lisp?

Tags: unit-testing, version-control, continuous-integration, common-lisp

Are there any continuous integration frameworks for CL?  Specifically, I'm looking for:

Automated "build", i.e. ASDF system load from base state

Automated tests

Status push - email notification and the like, especially for broken builds and failed tests

Status pull - website, logs, anything the dev team can pull to read

Status history - details of runs saved and easily browsable

It seems to me that the open source side of the Lisp community champions solo development.  There's very little in support for teams.  Just creating a project trunk with lib dependencies that can be checked out by a random developer has to be hand-rolled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/), it is very simple and language independent. The only requirement is that you can start the whole thing from a batch file, and return an value other than 0 when an error occurs. We use this for Java, C++, and Ruby projects.

Maybe this helps too: If your program does not return an error code, you can write a little script that runs after the program that checks the output logs for errors and returns an error code if something is found.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.  This seems to be the most actively developed open source project, and the extensibility is a good feature.  I'll try my hand at rolling some plugins for CL.